# Is there any way to delete ubercart role expiration through rules in Drupal 7

Tags: rules, ubercart, users

I am using Drupal 7 and ubercart roles where I have given the role expiration period of 1 day,
and with that role the user can create one node.
I want that as soon as the new node is created the role expiration should be deleted.

I am able to remove the role through rules but as the expiration period is still set, it cannot be re-assigned the role the same role if the user purchases the same role again,

Is there any way to remove the role expiration of ubercart?

thanks for any help.

Comment: you cant use this one? https://drupal.org/project/role_expire and then the API, retrieve expiry dates for given roles?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are removing the role through the drupal standard rules. Try calling the own uc_ubercart function to better compatibility.

```
/**
 * Deletes an expiration using user id or user id and rid.
 *
 * This function deletes expirations associated with users and roles. If
 * no role ID is passed, the function deletes all role expirations associated
 * with the given user. Otherwise, the function only deletes expirations whose
 * user and role IDs match. If any roles were actually deleted, the function
 * notifies the user. The menu cache is then flushed, as privileges to view
 * menu items may have been lost in the process.
 *
 * @param $account
 *   A Drupal user object.
 * @param $rid
 *   A Drupal role ID.
 * @param $silent
 *   When set to TRUE will suppress any Drupal messages from this function.
 */
uc_roles_delete($account, $rid = NULL, $silent = FALSE) {}
```

An example with custom module (without rules):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_insert().
 */
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {

  if ($node->type == 'customtype') {
    $rid = 3; //@TODO: set rol ID
    $account = user_load($node->uid);
    // Delete UC Role!
    uc_roles_delete($account, $rid, TRUE);
  }

}
```

You can also use this code on the rules action PHP but I prefer the hook.